# Cannot access private property Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs::$entityChangeSet

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am working on a Symfony 2.7 project that manages videos. I am writing an entity listener that will check for changes to a video, then apply a label to the video if the ownerGroup property is being changed. Here is the logic I am trying to use:

```
public function preUpdate($video, $args)
{

    if(!array_key_exists('ownerGroup', $args->entityChangeSet)){
        return; 
    }
    $entity = $args->getEntity();

    //It looks like we're changing the ownerGroup property. 
    //Do some stuff here.

}
```

The problem is that I get the following when the function runs:

> Error: Cannot access private property
>   Doctrine\ORM\Event\PreUpdateEventArgs::$entityChangeSet

Is there a getter I can use to get around this problem? My IDE's code completion doesn't seem to think that such a function exists.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try accessing with the getter method, as example:

```
if(!array_key_exists('ownerGroup', $args->getEntityChangeSet())){
    return; 
}
```

More info in the doc [here](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/events.html#preupdate)